# passing a function to a function SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

Below is SML code to compute a definite integral using the trapezoidal method given input f=unary function, a & b=range to take integral under, and n=number of sub-intervals to divide the range into.

```
    fun integrate f a b n =
let val w = (b - a) / (real n)
fun genBlock c = let val BB = f c
             val SB = f (c+w)
         in (BB + SB) * w / 2.0
         end
fun sumSlice 0 c acc = acc
  | sumSlice n c acc = sumSlice (n-1) (c+w) (acc + (genBlock c))
in sumSlice n a 0.0
end
```

Problem is I can't figure out for the life of me how to define a function (say X cubed) and feed it to this function with a,b, and n. Here's a screenshot of me trying and receiving an error:
[image]

In this picture I define **cube x =x*x*x** and show it works, then try to feed it to the integrate function to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty specific: `integrate` is expecting a function of type `real -> real` but you defined a function, `cube`, of type `int -> int`.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1) Add a type annotation to the definition of `cube`:

```
- fun cube x:real = x*x*x;
val cube = fn : real -> real
```

And then:

```
- integrate cube 0.0 5.0 5;
val it = 162.5 : real
```

2) You can dispense with defining `cube` as a named function and just pass the computation as an anonymous function. In this case, SML's type inference mechanism gives the function `x => x*x*x` the intended type:

```
- integrate (fn x => x*x*x) 0.0 5.0 5;
val it = 162.5 : real
```